# Force rsync to output messages line-by-line

Tags: rsync, io, stdout

(I'm not sure if this question should go on StackOverflow or here. But the actual problem is with `rsync`, so on balance I reckon it's a Linux question. If admins disagree, by all means please migrate it.)

I'm trying to run `rsync` from another program (written in Ruby in this case, although it could just as easily be written in any other language) and capture its output line-by-line.

(In Ruby, this is done by way of the [`Open3#popen3`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Open3.html#method-i-popen3) and [`IO.select`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO.select) calls. In Python, one would use `asyncio.create_subprocess_shell`.)

However – and unlike pretty much all other terminal commands I have ever encountered – `rsync` absolutely *refuses* to write its output on a line-by-line basis when run in this way (i.e. when not run from the terminal with a real tty). Instead, it "buffers" its output and only sends it right at the end (or, presumably, when the buffer is full). Maybe it's not `flush`ing the pipe? Whatever the reason, this is a serious problem. It means my script can't show progress messages (such as a percentage) to the user; and we are instead presented with complete radio silence for an hour (or however long the operation takes).

I have read that the `--outbuf=L` parameter exists for precisely this situation. However, it **does not work**. At least on my version of rsync, which is 3.2.7.

Someone on the internet suggested the `--msgs2stderr` parameter, but that didn't help either.

I wrote a simple test in Python, to make sure it wasn't a Ruby issue, using a modified version of [this example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34027086). The results were the same, so the issue is presumably with rsync.

So, my question is simple: how do I *force* rsync to output progress messages line-by-line, rather than "saving them up" and printing them in a big dump at the end?

##### ADDITIONAL CLARIFICATION

I'm running `rsync` locally. Here's an example of the exact command I'm using:

```
rsync --verbose --msgs2stderr --progress --relative --links
--hard-links --perms --owner --group --times --sparse
--one-file-system --human-readable --delete --delete-excluded
--recursive --prune-empty-dirs --outbuf=L --from0
'/mnt/data' '/mnt/backup'
--exclude-from=/tmp/rsbackupexclusionlist20230816-2064241-6nghn7
```

I can confirm that my Ruby code handles other programs – such as `apt-get`, `git`, `make` or `debootstrap` – correctly. (I didn't know about `yes` and haven't tested it.)

My research in the meantime suggests that `rsync` doesn't flush its STDOUT or STDERR output properly when it detects there is no PTY attached.

I have had some success since then, executing `rsync` by way of Ruby's poorly-documented `PTY.spawn` instruction, which creates a PTY and attaches the output channel of the command to it. But it's not ideal. For one thing, it merges STDOUT and STDERR into a single stream.

If the vast majority of other software "just works", why is `rsync` refusing to play nice? And is there a way to make it work, without using `PTY.spawn`?

**And why does `--outbuf=L` do nothing??**

Comment: What's your precise example `rsync` command line that you're using for testing this scenario?

Comment: are you running rsync as client or as rsync daemon? If as client, are the log messages you're looking for created by the client or sent by the server to the client for printing? I'm looking through [rsync's logging source code](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/blob/2f9b963abaa52e44891180fe6c0d1c2219f6686d/log.c#L225), and honestly, for C, it's pretty sane and does nothing special. (Honestly, I still pity the fools that have handle strings in C; just not a language with the tools necessary for human-appropriate for strings. But the code is pretty clean. No "custom" buffering happening anywhere.)

Comment: If this were just tty detection by rsync, I'd expect the problem to appear on any pipe.  But looking at the output of `rsync -av dir/ /tmp/dir/ | cat -`, it's showing every line immediately and not batching.  I think we'll have to have a more explicit example of the problem.

Comment: Have you checked that your code is properly handling the output of some other program (like `yes`)?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify the above points.

Comment: What `rsync` version do you have? Do you parse stderr? Have you tried without `--msgs2stderr`?

Comment: As I said, I have rsync 3.2.7. I tried without `--msgs2stderr`. The problem occurs on both stderr and stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to replicate this.

I used rsync 3.2.7 and ran it from a python script that grabs stderr.  It shows the output immediately, not waiting until the end.

I didn't use the exact same rsync options (I'm not processing an exception list), but I think all the relevant ones are used.  (And I saw no difference whether including `--outbuf=L` or not.

See if you can replicate it with this program.

```py
import subprocess
import sys


s = subprocess.Popen(["rsync", "-av", "--msgs2stderr", "--outbuf=L", "--progress", "lots_o_files/", "lots2/", ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


while (True):
    nextline = s.stderr.readline()
    if nextline == b'' and s.poll() is not None:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(nextline.decode())
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Output:

```
sending incremental file list
8m28V3/qG81EA/TViGDb/
8m28V3/qG81EA/TViGDb/XOarqQ.txt
            755 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, ir-chk=1008/15161)
8m28V3/qG81EA/TViGDb/Zhe0F6.txt
            742 100%  724.61kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, ir-chk=1007/15161)
8m28V3/qG81EA/TViGDb/a1B3ha.txt
            847 100%  827.15kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3, ir-chk=1006/15161)
...
```

If this prints output immediately, then the rsync must be producing the output immediately (without a TTY).   If this waits until the end, then there's something different with our systems (or the rsync options I didn't replicate are relevant).

Comment: Okay, this is really weird. Not only does rsync work as expected with your example, but now it also works with the test code I tested against before posting my question(!) My actual "production" code still didn't work, but I managed to fix it. There were a number of edge-case problems, most notably Ruby's `readline` doesn't work with rsync whilst `gets` does. Your guess there is as good as mine.

Comment: Interestingly, the "broken" code works perfectly well with `git`, `apt-get`, `make`.....and `yes`! It was only `rsync` it had problems with. But anyhow, your answer helped me, so thank you.